# mysqli send email loop

Tags: php

I'm stuck on this piece of code and hoping the brilliant minds here can help. :) I'm doing a query that results in two email addresses being selected from the database. Rather than sending ONE email to EACH recipient, my code sends an email to the first recipient with BOTH emails in it.

In other words, recipient A gets an email that says,

Hello, Recipent A
MESSAGE

and

Hello, Recipient B
MESSAGE

---

Recipient B gets no message at all.

Here is the code. Any help you can provide is appreciated!!!!

```
$sql2="SELECT c.email, c.fname FROM c INNER JOIN c_zip_save ON c.username = c_zip_save.username WHERE c_zip_save.zip_code = $zip";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql2); 
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
$rows[] = $row;
}

foreach($rows as $row)
{
$c_email = $row["email"];
$c_fname = $row["fname"];
$recipient2 = "$c_email";
$subject2 = "SUBJECT";
$message2 .= "Hi, $c_fname! \n\nThis is an automated courtesy message\n\n";

$extra2 = "From: myemail@myemail.com\r\n";

mail ($recipient2, $subject2, $message2, $extra2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you keep appending to your `$message2` string without resetting it each time. You could either reset it at the start of the foreach loop with `$message2 = "";` or change the `$message2 .= "your message"` to just `$message2 = "your message"`

Comment: No worries. While my answer solved the problem, I would recommend using the `sprintf()` style that @Your Common Sense used in their answer.

Comment: It'd also be nice if you could accept either mine or @Your Common Sense's answer, if we helped at all.

Comment: I'm sorry... still new here and didn't realize that I could. I tried to vote it up but I didn't have the rep. Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$message = "Hi, %s! \n\nThis is an automated courtesy message\n\n";

foreach($rows as $row)
{
    ...
    mail ($recipient2, $subject2, sprintf($message, $c_fname), $extra2);
}
```